# Change over time controlling for size of start point

Tags: controlling-for-a-variable

I have some data on a group of people.

The data look like these (each column is separated by a comma, values in top row are variable names, the dataset has c100 rows in total):

```
individual, score in 2006, score in 2014, diff
person 1, 252, 289, 37
person 2, 260, 285, 25
person 3, 262, 279, 17
person 4, 301, 315, 14
person 5, 321, 329, 8
person 6, 300, 308, 8
```

It appears that persons 1-3 have made the most progress since 2006 while persons 4-6 have made poorer progress. However, I need to control for the starting point—note that persons 4-6 had a higher starting point.

So to see which person have made the best progress, whilst controlling for the starting point, which one of these calculations is best:

```
diff/score in 2006
```

or

```
score in 2006/diff
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just between those two then you definitely want to go with the former, since the latter has that nasty asymptote towards infinity as the difference goes to zero.  (You might not actually see the asymptotic behavior if your measures are in whole numbers, but looking at the limit shows why it's almost certainly a bad measure.)

Not mentioned, perhaps because it's irrelevant in this case, is controlling for population mean and nonlinearities in the scoring system.  For example, rather than normalize by an individual's score you may want to normalize by the average score or some reference score.  And if this is an I.Q.-type (i.e., normally-distributed) score than it's far more significant to go from a tail 300 to 308 than it is to go from, say, 260 to 268.